# Bad int8 external representation

Tags: netezza, drilldown

In my report, I created a data item using a case statement that puts order revenue amounts into groups like $0-$999, $1000-$1500, etc.  I am trying to create a drilldown off of that data item but I am getting the below error message:

> Data source adapter error: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR: Bad int8 external representation "$0-$999"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code in question?

Comment: Are you looking for the SQL code?

Comment: If that's the code that's producing the error, yes. Please see [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable code sample for the problem in question.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way I can shrink down the code enough to fit into this comment box.

Comment: It shouldn't go in the comment box anyway, it should go in the question itself.

Comment: No luck.  Still too long.

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if we can't see the code in question? Without that about all we could possibly do is guess.

Comment: Not really my fault if I can't fit the code in the tool provided.

Comment: It's probably not necessary to copy *all* of the code - we just need to see the part of the code that's relevant to your question. I'd again point you to [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a **minimal**, verifiable, and complete example. Incidentally, exactly how long *is* the query?